# Querying CouchDB View With 2 fields With Each Field It's Own Values To Compare (AND Query with SQL)

Tags: couchdb, nosql

How to I query this CouchDB view below:

```
"by_credentials": {
    "map": "function(doc) {
        if(doc.username && doc.password) {
            emit([doc.username, doc.password], doc);
        }
    }"
}
```

I tried post method with JSON Payload:

```
http://localhost:5984/credentials/_design/default/_view/by_credentials
```

Payload:

```
{"key":["Jim","pass"]}
```

Please note I used key instead of keys because I'm not querying the same field for multiple values which I have no problem with. The problem is I'm querying 2 fields with each it's own values to compare with. Similar to SQL's AND query:

```
SELECT FROM doc WHERE doc.username="Jim" AND doc.password="pass"
```

Please help, I tried a lot of possible ways this might work, done a lot of readings and seems there are no simple but complete example with:
1) view
2) url
3) payload

Comment: Does it work using query parameters?

Comment: Yes this worked: 

    http://localhost:5984/credentials/_design/default/_view/by_credentials?key=["Jimbo","pass"] any secure way to do it?

Comment: What do you consider insecure about using query parameters? Your query as stated in your comment above seems fine to me.

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't want a password sent as a query parameter because those are logged server side (even if you use SSL).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=post%20view#post--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view) only `keys` can be sent as the body of a post request to a view.

However, you should be able to post a keys array with a single key:

```
{ "keys": [ [ "Jim", "pass" ] ] }
```